# Hide multiple shipping methods based on product IDs in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I want to hide a set of shipping methods if a set of products are selected on WooCommerce

I think I'm almost there but I am getting an error on the `unset( $rates[$method_ids] )` line.

Here's what I've got so far:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'specific_products_shipping_methods_hide_many', 10, 2 );
function specific_products_shipping_methods_hide_many( $rates, $package ) {

    $product_ids = array( 240555 ); // HERE set the product IDs in the array
    $method_ids = array( 'flat_rate:7', 'flat_rate:13', 'flat_rate:26', 'flat_rate:27', 'local_pickup:24' ) ; // HERE set the shipping method IDs
    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items Checking for defined product IDs
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $product_ids ) ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( $found )
        unset( $rates[$method_ids] );

    return $rates;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but you need to loop through `$rates` and if it occurs `$rate_id`, you can unset it

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Set the product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array( 240555, 30 );
    
    // Set the rate IDs in the array
    $rate_ids = array( 'flat_rate:7', 'flat_rate:13', 'flat_rate:26', 'flat_rate:27', 'local_pickup:24', 'local_pickup:1', 'free_shipping:2' );
    
    // Initialize
    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items checking for defined product IDs
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        // Checks if a value exists in an array
        if ( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $product_ids ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $found ) {
        // Loop trough
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            // Checks if a value exists in an array
            if ( in_array( $rate_id, $rate_ids ) ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_id] );
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```